# How to get value from key using Aeson's Parser from very simple Object`

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm trying to parse some JSON.

Given a very simple `[Object]` how can I get the `Value` under a string key?

**Attempt one (guessing):**

`d . key "test"`

Errors with:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Parser [Object]’
                  with actual type ‘(Value -> f0 Value) -> c0’
```

**Attempt two (from reading https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-lens-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html):**

```
d ^. key "test"
```

Errors with:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Parser [Object]’
              with actual type ‘Value’
```

---

Full code:

```
{-# Language OverloadedStrings #-}
module JobManagerApi where

import Network.Wreq
import Job
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens (_String, key)
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.ByteString.Lazy

-- parseResponse :: ByteString -> Either String String
parseResponse z = do
  result <- eitherDecode z
  flip parseEither result (\obj -> do
          d <- obj .: "data"
          -- k <- d . key "test"
          return (d :: [Object])
        )

apiPendingJobs :: IO [Job]
apiPendingJobs = do
  r <- get "http://localhost:3000/user_job_queue"
  let x = (r ^. responseBody)
  print $ parseResponse x
  pure []
```

The relavent bit being:

```
  flip parseEither result (\obj -> do
          d <- obj .: "data"
          -- k <- d . key
          return (d :: [Object])
        )
```

Comment: Yes I completely overlooked the fact I was already using it somehow to fetch the "data" key......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d .: "test"
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:.:

> Retrieve the value associated with the given key of an Object. The
>   result is empty if the key is not present or the value cannot be
>   converted to the desired type.